# Django Call Built in validator from defined validator

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

Can I call a Built-in django validator from my own defined validator ?
Here my **form.py**

```
def validate_trx_no(value):
    if not re.match(r'^[A-Za-z0-9]+$',value) :
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Document Number Format")
    elif #SomeBuiltInValidator like MinLengthValidator
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Document Number Length")

class TrxDetailForm(forms.Form):
    trx_no = forms.CharField(label='Number'
                        ,required=True
                        ,validators=[validate_trx_no])
```

**Note : I know basicly it suposed to called from TrxDetailForm class, but I want to know is that possible to call it from validate_trx_no() ?**

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I don't know how to write it, because MinLengthValidator class has 2 params (min length and message). I dont know how to parse the value